# VCAP ROUTER: 404 - DESTINATION NOT FOUND

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmc

I have some problem with my single node cloudfoundry which I installed in Virturalbox
(Ubuntu 11.10 server version)

I installed cloudfoundry successfully and push my first app written in ruby up to the cloudfoundry

when I check `vmc apps` I can see my app "RUNNING"
but when I try to connect from outside (HOST OS)

I put `192.168.11.51` in my browser's url (which is my vm's ip address)
and it only shows

> VCAP ROUTER: 404 - DESTINATION NOT FOUND

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is a problem with dns. To know which app to route requests to, CF needs to look at the Host: header basically.

So what you should do is make sure that the external IP of your VM is known as *.vcap.me

Comment: I have edited my /etc/hosts file like this:
127.0.0.1 api.vcap.me env.vcap.me

but it doesn't work, is there any problem with my setting?
I thought the only thing I need to do is typing LAN address of VM in my host os, so that I can connect to env.vcap.me
is it right?

Comment: hey, I figured out the problem... I forgot to setting the port number..
anyway, thank you for your time